# SE Data Explorer: Time Series of top-rated R posts by month & year

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a time series of top-rated R posts by month & year from the SE data explorer using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/436124/time-series-of-r-highest-rated-questions#messages). Here is the query I have written:

```
select Id, Title, Score, year(CreationDate) as creation_year, 
  month(CreationDate) as creation_month from Posts pp  
  inner join(max(Score) as max_score, year(CreationDate) as creation_year, 
    month(CreationDate) as creation_month from Posts 
  group by year(CreationDate),  month(CreationDate)) grouped_pp 
  on pp.creation_year = grouped_pp.creation_year 
  and pp.creation_month = grouped_pp.creation_month
  and pp.Score = grouped_pp.max_score
  where tags = '<r>'
```

However, this fails with the unhelpful:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Not sure how to fix this query.

Comment: I've remove the `r` tag as this is purely an `sql` question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you miss a `select` after `join`;

```
select 
    Id, 
    Title, 
    Score, 
    year(CreationDate) as creation_year, 
    month(CreationDate) as creation_month 
from Posts pp  
inner join (
    select
        max(Score) as max_score, 
        year(CreationDate) as creation_year, 
        month(CreationDate) as creation_month 
    from Posts 
    group by year(CreationDate),  month(CreationDate)
) grouped_pp 
on year(pp.CreationDate) = grouped_pp.creation_year 
and month(pp.CreationDate) = grouped_pp.creation_month
and pp.Score = grouped_pp.max_score
where tags = '<r>'
```

You  have  to  modify `pp.creation_year` to `year(pp.CreationDate)` [and  same for  `month`] to make the query  work

To   get the desired  result you may need  to use  two  other table  like, `PostTags` and `tags`;

```
select 
    Id, 
    Title, 
    Score, 
    creation_year, 
    creation_month
from (
    select
        p.Id,
        p.Title,
        p.Score,
        year(p.CreationDate) as creation_year,
        month(p.CreationDate) as creation_month,
        rank() over(partition by year(p.CreationDate), month(p.CreationDate) order by p.Score desc) rnk
    from Posts p 
    join PostTags pt on pt.postid = p.Id
    join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
    where t.tagname  =  'r'
) x
where rnk  = 1
order by creation_year, creation_month
```

Here  is the  [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/436525)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. One additional question -- how would I check if "r" is _one_ of the tags rather than the only tag? Also, I just checked the query (made one change -- `CreationDate` needs to be `select`ed from `pp`), and it does not appear to return any data. Can you help figure out why?